# Where to put `setxkbmap` command in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, xkb

What is the proper place for `setxkbmap` command in Xfce? What is the proper place for it in general - other DEs and bare WMs? I have the following command:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us(colemak), ru(typewriter)" -option "grp:menu_toggle"
```

Putting it in `.xsession` didn't work. I want to make this command run, to make it work globally in GUI.

**Edit (18.09.12):** I went `xfce4-settings-manager` -> `Session and Startup` -> `Application Autostart`, then clicked "Add". There i tried to put two commands to make it work.

1. The full `setxkbmap` command that i gave above verbatim under "Command".
2. Created an executable file with the command in my PATH, put the file name under "Command".

Both variants didn't work. However the *full path* to the executable file with the command under "Command" text field worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc ~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc
```

Then edit that file you just copied to and add anything you want. Your script will take precedence over the system one.

Take heed of the comments, however, since session manager will take over and any part of the script that comes after it won't be executed. Put your line somewhere before that.

However, if might also work to open the settings manager and select Keyboard, and Layout tab. Try making changes there. But I'm not sure you can do there what you need.

Answer (score 8):

"Anywhere"

You can put that as an autostart command, in `xfce4-settings-manager` -> `Startup`, and add a command (If you launch X with `startx` command, just put that line in ~/.xinitrc)

Or put the corresponding xkbconfig in Xorg.conf, e.g `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/XX.conf`, with the following

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Keyboard Options by default"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"

    Option "XkbLayout" "us , ru"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:menu_toggle"
EndSection
```