# Where to put commands to run when X starts with SLiM

Tags: x11, login, slim

I'm having trouble determining where to add these two commands:

```
setxkbmap latam
```

to set the correct keyboard layout, and

```
xcompmgr -c -C &
```

to enable transparency.

Before installing SLiM, I used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47388/42722) recommendation, and it worked, but it stopped working afterwards.

I tried adding it to ~/.xinitrc, like shown below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

exec setxkbmap latam
exec xcompmgr -c -C &
exec startxfce4
```

But this seemed to crash it, and it just froze before starting XFCE4 (after logging in).

I also tried using [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Keyboard_settings) recommendation from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org), but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any recommendations? Note that I'd like these commands to be the default setting for all users that log into xfce4.

Comment: Check this article http://wiki.xfce.org/tips, into the **How to customize starting Xfce** section you can find some useful data. Personally I think you should add `setxkbmap latam` and `xcompmgr -c -C` into your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here:

```
exec setxkbmap latam
exec xcompmgr -c -C &
exec startxfce4
```

You'd have better luck with:

```
setxkbmap latam
xcompmgr -c -C &
exec startxfce4
```

`exec` replaces the shell that was receiving input, which makes sense for starting a graphical environment (so that it will receive the input), but not much sense for the other two.